# Quadratic Operator Notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, operator-theory

I am dealing with functions that are linear combinations of:

$[x_1^2, x_2^2... x_n^2, x_1x_2, x_1x_3... x_n-1x_n]$

spanned over a column.

All these functions obey the law:

$F(aX) = a^2F(X)$ for constant values a.

Is there a notation for handling these? Similar to matrix notation for linear operators over $R^n$ (in fact matrices work just fine over $C^n$ as well) does there exist some type of concise "box of numbers and stuff" notation for handling quadratic operators?

I tried designing my own notations which almost work fine except:

1. If I allow both pure polynomials (ex: $x^3$ and $y^2$) and mixed polynomials (ex: $x^3y^2) handling composition using a box of numbers notation doesn't appear straightforward.
2. If I allow only pure polynomials then I have a syntax for working with matrix-like objects that can handle composition just fine (it generalizes cleanly to higher powers) but I lose the ability to handle mixed expressions.

The factoring of constant values and handling sum of expression are both fine in both notations.

How do I create an all encompassing notation in case one does not exist?

Comment: Maybe you do not want to allow composition and multiplication because these operations "expand" the space. If you restrict to homogeneous polynomials, you can be sure that the result is homogeneous, but the degree can still increase. An all encompassing notation would be, in my opinion, the whole expression itself. By that I mean you keep a list of pairs of the form (coefficient, monomial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In characteristic not 2) every [quadratic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) $Q(x)$ has an associated symmetric bilinear form $B(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(Q(x+y) - Q(x) - Q(y))$. We have $Q(x) = B(x,x)$. Since symmetric bilinear forms can be represented by symmetric matrices, this means there is a symmetric matrix $A$ such that

$$ Q(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T A \vec{x} $$

Of course, this last fact could be seen directly, by observing that every $x_i x_j$ appears in $\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}$ with independent coefficients from $A$ (even in characteristic $2$, although we can't insist on symmetry in that case). I wanted to point out that quadratic forms and bilinear forms are closely connected.

For higher degree homogeneous polynomials, you'd have to appeal to multi-linear algebra, which would involve higher rank tensors. In fact, the quadratic form really ought to be a rank (0,2) tensor (or maybe (2,0); I forget the convention) rather than a matrix, which is a rank (1,1) tensor

Comment: Not sure if I have learned something since I posed the question or just was plain stupid since this made perfect sense today